# HERE Android Premium SDK Native engine initialization failed

Tags: android

When use premium SDK for android,I cannot init the mapFragment.Flowing is the error message

```
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.nokia.maps.aw.a(EngineError.java:27)
    at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine$h.a(MapsEngine.java:856)
    at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine$h.a(MapsEngine.java:732)
    at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine$h.doInBackground(MapsEngine.java:716)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
       (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
       .run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is my fault,I used a wrong apptoken.